# Sitecore Client freezes when deleting an item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, content-editor

I have this project on Sitecore 8.1 and it works quite ok. Recently I had to migrate it to an other server. I restored the databases on a new server, I've copied the website folder, and started on the new server.

All is good, except one thing: when I delete an item the client freezes. 
I have a log line like this

> 23144 10:52:39 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Recycle item:
>   master:/sitecore/content/Home/myfolder/myitem

After I shutdown the website an error appears in the log:

> 22592 11:07:07 ERROR Error while deleting items Exception:
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException Message: Thread was being
>   aborted. Source: mscorlib    at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object
>   obj)    at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String
>   configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingManager.UpdateIndexAsync(Database
>   database)    at Sitecore.MainUtil.RaiseEvent[T](EventHandler1
>   subscribers, Object sender, T eventArgs)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemDeleted(Item item, ID
>   oldParentId)    at System.EventHandler1.Invoke(Object sender,
>   TEventArgs e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler1
>   handlers, Func2 argsCreator)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.DoArchiveItems(IEnumerable`1 items,
>   ID archivalId)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func1 action,
>   Action recover)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.ArchiveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Recycle()    at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.Delete(List1 items)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.Execute(ClientPipelineArgs
>   args)

I'm not sure if this is related to the client freeze or is just because I shut down the app before deletion ended.

Do any of you have any idea why the client freezes?

Comment: Does you application have access to your indexes (also write)?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check that ?

Comment: Check the permissions on the folder were the indexes are located and check the security rights. As you do have logs, you could compare them with the log folder. Not sure that this is your issue, just a possibility..

Comment: I rebuilt all the indexes including the search index, changed the permissions on the folder ( as you said) and I fixed it. Thank you for the idea. If you post it as an answer I mark it as THE answer :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions of the indexes folder (security for your application's user). Probably the user will not be able to write to the folder. 
You can compare the security settings with those on your log folder as that seems to work fine.

Might be a good idea to rebuild indexes to make sure you have all updates.